# characters are not displaying in japanese with visual studio 2013

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, encoding, iis-express

I am using this "http://marios.com.gr/keyboard_v2/" jquery plugin in visual studio 2013. After choosing language japanese, keyboard characters are not displaying in japanese.

[image: Displaying as in image]

Comment: Do you have the japanese font installed on your computer?

Comment: No..how i can check that or install the japanese font?

Comment: On which OS are you?

Comment: But it display correctly, if don't run from visual studio. Only add the plugin to normal html page with jquery.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Window 8

Comment: Ok so nevermind, it should not be related in this case

Comment: What i need to do to make it work correctly?